# Having problems in accessing textbox in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am getting an error("input string was not in a correct format") every time I click the lnkUpdate button. Am i missing something? I can't find what's wrong with the codes in the updating event

aspx

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Received</th>
            <th>Remaining</th>
            <th>Ordered</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>    
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <asp:ListView ID="lvSODetails" runat="server" 
            onitemcanceling="lvSODetails_ItemCanceling" 
            onitemediting="lvSODetails_ItemEditing" 
            onitemupdating="lvSODetails_ItemUpdating" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Eval("ProductID") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("ProductName") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Received") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Remaining")%></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Quantity") %></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" 
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlDetails" runat="server" DefaultButton="lnkUpdate">
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' /></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("ProductName") %></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtQtyReceived" runat="server" /></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblRemaining" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Remaining") %>' /></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Quantity") %></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" 
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" CommandName="Update" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" 
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </asp:Panel>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

c# code

```
protected void lvSODetails_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    lvSODetails.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GetInfo();
    GetDetails();
}
protected void lvSODetails_ItemCanceling(object sender, ListViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    lvSODetails.EditIndex = -1;
    GetInfo();
    GetDetails();
}
protected void lvSODetails_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string ProdID = (lvSODetails.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("lblID") as Label).Text;
    string Received = (lvSODetails.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("txtQtyReceived") as TextBox).Text;
    string Remaining = (lvSODetails.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("lblRemaining") as Label).Text;
    if (int.Parse(Received) < 0) //   <~ this is where the code stops (error"input string was not in a correct format")
    {
        error.Visible = true;
        lblError.Text = "Items received must not be lower than zero";
    }
    else if (int.Parse(Received) >= 0 && int.Parse(Received) <= int.Parse(Remaining))
    {
        SODetails = (DataTable)Session["sodelivery"];
        foreach (DataRow row in SODetails.Rows)
        {
            if (row["ProductID"].ToString() == ProdID)
            {
                row["Received"] = Received;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    lvSODetails.EditIndex = -1;
    GetInfo();
    GetDetails();
}
```

~~~~ Edit ~~~~

listview databinding code

```
void GetDetails()
    {
        if (SODetails == null)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT sod.ProductID, p.ProductName, sod.SOQtyReceived AS Received, " +
                "(sod.SOQtyOrdered - sod.SOQtyReceived) AS Remaining, sod.SOQtyOrdered AS Quantity FROM SODetails AS sod " +
                "INNER JOIN Products AS p ON sod.ProductID=p.ProductID WHERE sod.SONo=@SONo";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SONo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
            SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            SODetails = new DataTable();
            data.Fill(SODetails);

            DataRow[] rowList = SODetails.Select();
            foreach (DataRow dr in rowList)
            {
                dr["Received"] = "0";
            }
            lvSODetails.DataSource = SODetails;
            lvSODetails.DataBind();
            con.Close();
            Session["sodelivery"] = SODetails;
        }
        else
        {
            lvSODetails.DataSource = SODetails;
            lvSODetails.DataBind();
            Session["sodelivery"] = SODetails;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post only the section of code that demonstrates the problem? Which line is throwing the error? I'm guessing it's one of the int.Parse calls, but which? What's in those string variables when they're being called?

Comment: @eddie_cat it looks like string received does not return a value..ProdID and Remaining returns a value when i tested but when it comes to received, it seems to be not returning a value

Comment: Your `Received` is not in the correct string format that can be parsed into an integer. Check where that variable came from.

Comment: Can you add the code that sets up the databinding for the ListView in the code behind please?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem isn't that you can't access the TextBox.

Use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of int.Parse since you are reading user input.

```
        int received;
        if (!int.TryParse(Received, out received) || received < 0)
        {
                error.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "Items received must not be lower than zero";
        }
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if `int.Parse()` fails every time, then `int.TryParse()` is going to fail every time too. The latter just handles the error, it doesn't actually fix the problem at hand.

Comment: It will fail every time if the user leaves the value blank or enters an invalid value every time.  All you can do is code in a way that prevents Exceptions from getting thrown because of invalid user input.

Comment: @j.f. regarding my previous note: however if its invalid every time, even with valid user input, then yes we have a separate problem going on.